# Using DataBase and Dict to Add Menus and Triggers

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, pyqt, pyqt5

Im trying to make my menu auto generated using this for loop:

```
q3 = connect_menu.addMenu('Q3')
q3menus = {}
x = 0
for element in q3s:
    key = 'Q'+str(x)
    q3menus[key] = QAction(element[7], self)
    q3.addAction(q3menus[key])
    q3menus[key].triggered.connect(lambda: self.main_form.consavesv(q3menus[key].text()))
    x += 1
```

`q3s` equals to a Fetchall function that gets the data from last SQL Query

`q3s = [(1, 'Q3', '127.0.0.1', 28960, "Server Test Name", '5154', '127.0.0.1:28960', "127.0.0.1:28960 | Server Test Name"), (2, 'Q3', '192.168.1.66', 28960, 'Server Test 2', '5154', '192.168.1.66:28960', '192.168.1.66:28960 | Server Test 2')]`

I tried to use a dictianory, This dictianory adds menu labels as well as it should, but when I click on them I they all have the same `triggered.connect()` as the last one does..

What Im doing wrong ?

I dont want to create Signals myself in here, Cause the Database Results are not static.

Comment: I guess I should add `triggered.connect()` outside the loop, but I have no Idea then how should I set `triggered.connect()` for all items in dictianory

Comment: you could show what you get when you run `print(q3s)`

Comment: @eyllanesc question updated and q3s content added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

he problem is the way you pass the parameters to a lambda function, the correct syntax is:

```
f = lambda p_1, p_2, ..., p_n: some operation with p_1, p_2, ..., p_n
```

In your case you must also take into account that the triggered signal of `QAction` returns a value called checked, so you must precede that parameter as shown below:

```
q3menus[key].triggered.connect(lambda checked, key=key: self.main_form.consavesv(q3menus[key].text()))
```

In addition to this approach you can also use the `sender()` method that returns the object that emits the signal and get the text directly as shown in the following example:

```
class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        q3s = [(1, 'Q3', '127.0.0.1', 28960, "Server Test Name", '5154', '127.0.0.1:28960', "127.0.0.1:28960 | Server Test Name"), 
        (2, 'Q3', '192.168.1.66', 28960, 'Server Test 2', '5154', '192.168.1.66:28960', '192.168.1.66:28960 | Server Test 2')]
        menubar = self.menuBar()

        q3 = menubar.addMenu("Q")
        q3menus = {}
        for x, element in enumerate(q3s):
            key = 'Q'+str(x)
            q3menus[key] = QAction(element[7], self)
            q3.addAction(q3menus[key])
            q3menus[key].triggered.connect(lambda checked, key=key : self.someFunction(q3menus[key].text()))
            q3menus[key].triggered.connect(self.anotherFuntions)

    def someFunction(self, text):
        print("someFunction {}".format(text))

    def anotherFuntions(self):
        print("anotherFuntions {}".format(self.sender().text()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.show()    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It worked!! Can u explain `q3menus[key].triggered.connect(lambda checked, key=key : self.someFunction(q3menus[key].text()))` for me ?

Comment: the triggered signal returns a parameter that indicates if it has been checked since a QAction can be checkeable, but by default it is not, but we must take it into account, then we must pass the other parameters by assigning them, to clarify the above is equivalent to: `q3menus[key].triggered.connect(lambda checked, param=key : self.someFunction(q3menus[param].text()))`