# How can we open a tab specific tab in pyqt on button click?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4, qtabwidget

i have made 10 tabs in my design page using qt designer and have made a menu bar on the top of it. 
Now i want to connect one of the options in the menubar to a tab (say tab 5).
i.e. when i click on menu->button then the tab5 gets opened

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To open a tab you must use the `setCurrentIndex()` method of the `QTabWidget`, to this method you must indicate the index. The above must be executed each time the triggered signal associated with the `QAction` of the menu

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        widget = QTabWidget(self)
        for i in range(10):
            widget.addTab(QListWidget(), "tab{}".format(i+1))

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        action = menubar.addAction("Select tab5")
        action.triggered.connect(lambda: widget.setCurrentIndex(4))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

*plus:*

```
    self.Add_GroupD.triggered.connect(lambda checked, index1=4, index2=1 : self.someslot(index1, index2))
def someslot(self, index1, index2)
    self.tabWidget_4.setCurrentIndex(index1)
    self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(index2)
```

Comment: This Worked Thanks but i have somemore to do here. i have tabs inside tabs in which i want to navigate say after button click i got to tab 5 and now i wanted to be in tab2 inside tab5..could you help me with this too? sorry for the fact that i m extending my question now :)

Comment: What is missing?

Comment: Show your code to understand better, I understand that with the click on the button access tab5, as I show in my example, before which action do you want to select the nested tab2?

Comment: self.Add_GroupD.triggered.connect(lambda : self.tabWidget_4.setCurrentIndex(4))
        self.Add_GroupD.triggered.connect(lambda : self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(1))

Comment: yup i wanted to go to nested tab2 exactly. you have a better idea than this?

Comment: Working Great thanks can this function be generic? if i could send index1 and index2 as args i could reuse the function easily for every nest as i have many nests but if this cannot be generic then maybe there wouldn't be need of function here as it wouldn't modularize my code anyhow

Comment: see my answer :P

Comment: Works like a Fire :P thanks again i think you can help me alot with QT

Comment: see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46396422/using-database-and-dict-to-add-pyqt5-menus-and-triggers-python-3/46396590#46396590 and your comments.